# Asus N55SL "No Sound" on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers

I have Asus N55SL Laptop.
I installed Windows 10 Enterprise Build 18362.30
And after that my Realtek sound driver won’t match with device.
I searched a lot and I tried to fix it in multiple ways. But non of them works.
In my previous windows 10 my Realtek driver version was V6.0.1.6631 and it perfectly matched with my device.
But in new windows I can’t get any sound and “High Definition Audio Controller” have a yellow warn sign in device manager, and there is no “sound, video and game controllers” in it.
I really want to uninstall windows 10 drivers for audio and try to reinstall Realtek.
Please help me, I want my audio back.
I imported an screenshot please check it.
Thanks.
[Asus n55sl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxvwK.png)

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution here:

https://www.tenforums.com/sound-audio/10067-realtek-hd-audio-non-sound-after-win-10-upgrade-5.html

> This problem occurs because you have installed Windows 10 on a GPT disk (you can check this on Disk Management: right-click your disk – usually Disk 0 – select Properties, Volumes tab, Partition style). Unfortunately the ASUS N55SF audio drivers are incompatible with GPT, so **the only solution is wipe your disk clean and reinstall Windows on an MBR formatted disk** (unless you have a Windows 7 partition on another disk and want to try my trick, though I don't recommend it). Here's the steps I suggest you to follow to make sure you install Windows on an MBR formatted disk:
>
> 1. **Burn your Windows 10 ISO on a DVD.** Yes, *burn.* Using a USB stick (FAT-32) I could only manage to install Windows 10 on GPT. No matter how I formatted my stick with Rufus, there was no way Windows would let me proceed the installation on an MBR disk. Using the good old DVD method could possibly spare you hours of frustration. And don't worry if you don't have anymore a DVD drive installed in your laptop: I was able to install Windows through a USB-SATA cable connected to my external drive.
> 2. We are going to completely wipe your disk, so make sure you **backup everything** you need before you proceed. **Boot your machine from the DVD** and let the procedure load. Once on the partitioning screen, delete all the present partitions until all you're left with is unallocated space.
> 3. Now hit Shift+F10 to get the command line. Type "diskpart" and hit enter. Run the following commands:
>
>    - `list disk`
>        (as to take note of the disk number you want to install Windows on)
>    - `select disk #`
>        (where *#* is the number of the desired disk, usually 0)
>    - `clean`
>    - `convert MBR`
>    - `create partition primary`
>    - `format fs=ntfs quick`
>    - `assign`
>    - `exit`
> 4. Now you can close your command line and hit "Refresh". Click on your freshly created primary partition and click "Next" to proceed with the Windows install.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone will find this useful. I just bought old Asus N55SL and after installing a fresh copy of Windows 10 the sound was gone. I had a triangle next to High Definition Audio Controller in the device manager. Nothing seemed to help. I've tried different drivers and couldn't install them because Windows wouldn't allow me. It seemed that I tried everything and finally found a solution. I enabled POST Sound in BIOS and after the restart the sound was working in Windows. Good luck

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).